# How do I install and configure TWiki?

Tags: software-installation

Could anyone tell me how to install and configure TWiki Release 5.1.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

I have seen some instructions on the TWiki website which applies to version 8.04:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 twiki
```

Would this install the latest release?

Comment: No... There is a good twiki ;) which describes how this can be done. You ought to check that out http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiOnUbuntu